# exporting datagridview to specific place in an existing word doc

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-word

I have a little program I  am trying to build in which there is a datagridview. Originally I just wanted to print this grid, but then decided I wanted to have headers, pre-written text, etc and I ***thought*** the easiest way would be to export it to a word document.

My grid is not populated by any database or anything, it is filled depending on what options are selected in the program. So you click a few options and fill in a few prices, then click a button and the options are added to the grid on another tab page by using dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

Now, I want to export the grid to a word doc. I have been through many questions on here, been on msdn and all the usual places but I can't find what I'm looking for. I found a tut on msdn which opened a new doc, inserted headers and tables and the like but the only thing I could use was

```
private void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object oMissing = Missing.Value;
        object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";

        //Start Word and create a new document.
        Word._Application oWord;
        Word._Document oDoc;
        oWord = new Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = true;
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    }
```

But I don't understand how to export from the grid??

Comment: anyone? I dont need it in a specific place now, just need to insert  DGV in to an existing word doc

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed it - this is what I ended up with for anyone whos interested;

```
Word._Application oWord;
                Word._Document oDoc;
                oWord = new Word.Application();
                oWord.Visible = true;
                object oTemplate = "C:/Users/Sean/Documents/Custom Office Templates/BMW Invoice.dotx";
                oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                Object start = Type.Missing;
                Object end = Type.Missing;
                object missing = System.Type.Missing;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = oDoc.Range(ref start, ref end);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl = oDoc.Tables.Add(rng, dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Row newRow = oDoc.Tables[1].Rows.Add(ref missing);
                newRow.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
                newRow.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
                tbl.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
                tbl.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble;
                tbl.Cell(0, 0).WordWrap = false;
                tbl.Cell(0, 0).FitText = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Exported");
                    else
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {

                            tbl.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Range.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
```